# Exclude Certain Posts From Wordpress's 'Recent Posts' in the Sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

How Can I Exclude Certain Posts From Wordpress's 'Recent Posts' in the Sidebar? I see a lot of content on excluding categories, not individual posts.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude posts from the Recent Posts widget via the `widget_posts_args` filter:

```
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'exclude_posts_wpse_103570');

function exclude_posts_wpse_103570( $args ){
    $args['post__not_in'] = array( 123, 234, 345 ); // replace with your post ids
    return $args;
}
```

Just copy this code into your theme's `functions.php` file.

This filter is located in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`. Source view [here](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/widget_posts_args?version=3.8&file=wp-includes/default-widgets.php).